# Octave Package Zenity returns error

Tags: octave, zenity

I am getting error while trying to get user input via

```
User_date=zenity_calendar()

error: datevec: none of the standard formats match the DATE string
error: called from
    datevec at line 137 column 11

    datestr at line 181 column 7

    zenity_calendar at line 42 column 7
```

It is

win7 64bit system.

Octave version 4.2.1

zenity *|   0.5.7 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\zenity-0.5.7

Any suggestion?

After debug.
pkg load zenity

> > d=zenity_calendar()
> >     status = 0
> >     output = 11/28/2017

datevec.m

line 142-146

```
  [f, rY, ry, fy, fm, fd, fh, fmi, fs] = ...
            __date_vfmt2sfmt__ (std_formats{l});
          [found y(k) m(k) d(k) h(k) mi(k) s(k)] = ...
            __date_str2vec__ (date{k}, p, f, rY, ry, fy, fm, fd, fh, fmi, fs);
```

results is

```
nd =  1
f = %m/%d/%Y
rY =  7
ry = 0
fy = 1
fm = 1
fd = 1
fh = 0
fmi = 0
fs = 0
found = 0
y = 0
m = 0
d = 0
h = 0
mi = 0
s = 0
```

I donot know how to fix it

Comment: You should try to debug this. start GNU Octave, `pkg load zenity; debug_on_error(1);zenity_calendar()` the debugger should now in datevec. use "dbup" until you are at zenity_calendar line 42 and inspect `status` and `output`. Btw, if you've never used the debugger: it's really worth to spent some hours to get familiar with it. It would have saved me weeks of fustration if I've learned it earlier.

Comment: @ Andy.. see my edit question. I ma using germa system date today=28.11.2017, how can I set zenity_calendar() to german system.